# Lotus notes - type mismatch

Tags: field, lotus-notes

I want to verify a field ( Numeric type ) value and I get the above error
The field name is `saved`.

I tried :

```
If Doc.saved = "1" Then 
...
End If
```

or

```
If Doc.GetItemValue("saved")(0) = "1" then ... End IF
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If Doc.saved(0) = 1 Then 
...
End If
```

will work. You have to get the first element of your item with `(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the double quotes from around the 1. You're comparing a numeric field to a string literal at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dropped the quotes, but still, the error exists